# main Differenece Between View-Based and Window-Based Application template?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode-template

What Is The Main Difference Between a View-Based Application Template And Window-Based Application Template In Iphone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The core idea is that a Window-based application template is more bare-bones than a View-based one. Use a view-based application template for projects that have a single view. Use a window-based application template (or another template) for other types of projects.

Answer (score 2):

View-Based Application Template has a UIView setup for you and
Window-Based Application Template doesn't.