# What application template should I use for my geolocation application?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode-template

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814575/main-differenece-between-view-based-and-window-based-application-template) about the differences in the window- and view-based iOS application templates in Xcode, but I'm still confused about what template to use in my iPhone app.

I am developing a geolocation app for service stations.  What template would be more appropriate for this: the view-based application template or the window-based one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice won't greatly affect your end product.  The real question is what template gets me closest to the app I'm designing.

The view-based application template is geared towards an app with a single view.  It's just a starting point, though, and you can always add more views/controllers to it afterwards.  There's nothing special in the view-based template that you couldn't add to a window-based template, as shown in this [blog post](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-view-based-application-from-scratch/).

Your app sounds like it might benefit more from a navigation-based template.  That will give you a UINavigationController and a UITableViewController to work with initially, and I'm guessing that would work well with your list of service stations.  Perhaps when a service station is selected, you'd push a geolocalisation (sp?) view controller showing the details of the service station?

Answer (score 1):

View-based Application description:

> This template provides a starting
>   point for an application that uses a
>   **single view**.

If your app's design contains only a single view, then choosing View-based Application will save you the trouble of creating and linking that view. Even if your app has more than one view, View-based can still save you the time of making that initial view. You want Window-based Application for when you know you're setting up something custom.

Comment: Hi, i decided to use a view-based application template for my app, i hope there is no big difference which may influence on the final purpose of my app :)))