# Split View-based template for iPad in horizontal?

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode-template

I´ve been reading different questions in StackOverFlow ( [What application template should I use for my geolocation application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340634/what-application-template-should-i-use-for-my-geolocation-application) or [main Differenece Between View-Based and Window-Based Application template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814575/main-differenece-between-view-based-and-window-based-application-template), for example) in order to understand which template would fit my app best. The Split view-based template feels to me like a good choice, since I want an application where the user can have a View where some content is displayed (let´s say, for example, an image) but also a set of miniatures of all the other elements available (the TableView). So if, while taking a look to the first image another one becomes available, this last one would appear in the the set of miniatures. In this way, the user could always access any received element, recognizing it by its miniature (snapshot alike).

The problem is that I would like to have the TableView displayed at the bottom in horizontal, because it gives a better idea of how the elements are chronologically displayed and the remaining space (in the view) fits better to what I have in mind. I was reading the Apple the documentation but without any luck.
So the actual question is; is there a way to make this template have the TableView as I want it to be?

If there is no possibility to change that, what would you suggest? I already started doing some coding, but I´m completely open to start again if someone has any suggestions of better templates or approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking at this link and the demonstration video that's there: http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/

The class he describes allows for either vertical or horizontal splits and can probably do what you want.